# How do I load a string table from outside application bundle on iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I would like to know how to load a resource string table from a file in application documents and not from application resource bundle or any other bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fileName" ofType:@"fileExtension"];
```

that will get you the path to the file fileName.fileExtension from the app bundle...

Comment: OP specifically asked for "not from resources".  Which makes no sense.  Either the string table should be in the app wrapper as a standard resource or it should be in the user's directory somewhere else as document-like data.

Comment: I want to download the string table from the web, probably in application cache. This is why I asked for a way to load them from outside the application.

Comment: 'from a web service' makes sense. WWDC 2010 had 2 talks about how to do network access on iOS. Please watch them.

Answer (score 1):

There is [NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html) method which means you would have to put the string table in a [NSBundle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSBundle).  Theory would be that you could download this NSBundle from the internet. Before you load your MainView Controller, you would load a controller that would check to make sure it has the latest version in [NSApplicationSupportDirectory](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/NSApplicationSupportDirectory).

This NSBundle cannot contain any binary code because it's against Apple App Store policy to download code in any way or form.

Comment: This is more inline with what the OP asked for